# Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D

Tags: javascript, canvas

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'
>       at drawCanvas (userscript.html?id=0e769594-f15d-490f-a75c-bac819525aab:56)
>       at setTimeout (userscript.html?id=0e769594-f15d-490f-a75c-bac819525aab:59)

I am trying to load images to a canvas based on url input, i've tried adding event listeners and a logger, none seem to work.

```
setTimeout(() => {

    let startpanel = document.getElementById('startpanel')

    // image for skin
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.style.width = "220px";
    img.style.height = "177px";

    // input custom skin
    var skinInput = document.createElement("input");
    skinInput.placeholder = "skin url";
    skinInput.style.width = "150px";
    skinInput.style.height = "35px";

    skinInput.onblur = function() {
        const newImage = new Image();
        newImage.src = skinInput.value;
        img.src = skinInput.value;
        drawCanvas(newImage);
      };

    startpanel.appendChild(skinInput)

    // draw skin
    var appearance = document.createElement("canvas");
    appearance.id = "appearance";
    // appearance.style.position = "absolute";
    appearance.style.top = "100px";
    appearance.style.width = "200px";
    appearance.style.height = "177px";
    appearance.style.border = "1px solid #d3d3d3";
    startpanel.appendChild(appearance)

    const drawCanvas = (newImage) => {
        var ctx = appearance.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(newImage, 10, 10);
      }

      drawCanvas();

}, 3000);
```

Comment: You are trying to draw the image before it is loaded. Setting `.src` starts loading the image asynchronously; if you want to draw it you need to set `.onload` to a function that does so. SO has multiple search results for the error btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this error is thrown because you call your own function **"drawCanvas(newImage)"** without argument after define it : **"drawCanvas()"**.

So, your function call the context function **drawImage** with a null first argument : **"ctx.drawImage(newImage, 10, 10)"**

If you remove the line **"drawCanvas()"** the error is not thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the image arugment passed to drawImage() method is not broken. Check its src if pointing to valid image source.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and the firefox, chromium dont show the image png, jpg (images download), i had created an image on my computer with extension png, the images had downloaded show in blank but my own image appears it may be a with the format of the image.

Note: i was woking linux antX distro the file name it doesnt have extension myimage becomes myimage.png.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this will work inside the onload method of an image, but not elsewhere. Example:

```
document.getElementById("imageId").onload = function() {
  var img = document.getElementById("imageId");
  var canvasElement = document.getElementById("canvasId");
  var ctx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

"I also wrote in this form
i remove .src from image.src
i put img instead img.src"

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
img.src = rutaImg;    
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);"
```